# Typescript/Javascript Call Method Reference with arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a bulk operation that operates on a 2 dimensional array. It shall call a given method "func" on each element in the array:

```
function forEachMatrixElement(matrix: Complex[][], func: Function): Complex[][] {
  let matrixResult: Complex[][] = new Array(countRows(matrix)).fill(false).map(() => new Array(countCols(matrix)).fill(false)); // Creates a result 2D-Matrix
  for (let row = 0; row < countRows(matrix); row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < countCols(matrix); col++) {
      matrixResult[row][col] = func.call(matrix[row][col]); // Call the given method
    }
  }
  return matrixResult;
}
```

I have two functions that I want to delegate to this method:
This one takes no additional arguments and works fine:

```
export function conjugateMatrix(matrix: Complex[][]): Complex[][] {
  return forEachMatrixElement(matrix, Complex.prototype.conjugate);
}
```

This one takes an additional argument (a scalar). But I don't know how to add this argument to this method reference on the prototype:

```
export function multiplyMatrixScalar(matrix: Complex[][], scalar: Complex): Complex[][] {
  return forEachMatrixElement(matrix, Complex.prototype.mul); // TODO Call with scalar
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reaching into the `prototype` and manipulating the value of `this` with `call()` is usually a bad idea. This can be made simpler.

Instead, the `forEachMatrixElement` should simply take a function that accepts a `Complex` instance, and the caller can decide what that function does and how to apply its arguments.

For example:

```
function forEachMatrixElement(
  matrix: Complex[][],
  func: (complex: Complex) => Complex // Changed this function type
): Complex[][] {
  let matrixResult: Complex[][] = new Array(countRows(matrix)).fill(false).map(() => new Array(countCols(matrix)).fill(false));
  for (let row = 0; row < countRows(matrix); row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < countCols(matrix); col++) {
     
      // just invoke the function like any other. No .call()
      matrixResult[row][col] = func(matrix[row][col]); 
      
    }
  }
  return matrixResult;
}
```

Now the functions that call this can simply be:

```
export function conjugateMatrix(matrix: Complex[][]): Complex[][] {
  return forEachMatrixElement(matrix, (c) => c.conjugate());
}

export function multiplyMatrixScalar(matrix: Complex[][], scalar: Complex): Complex[][] {
  return forEachMatrixElement(matrix, (c) => c.mul(scalar));
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-baHTQXR6g7aMwVwG2e2ACOI5GovOYrKbxhbbaLqWckmFglQwUXGAAynIFOuMOPMKPN7J5JYv1pQDJzwadq14Od6iaGll1XXojQwTdlh3IgEVvGQ30seFGxEIA)

Comment: Also I think your `forEachMatrixElement()` can be _much_ simpler with some simple `map()` calls. https://tsplay.dev/NrXJaW

Answer (score 2):

Could you just create a new function in `multiplyMatrixScalar`?

Something like:

```
export function multiplyMatrixScalar(matrix: Complex[][], scalar: Complex): Complex[][] {
  const fn = function (this: Complex) { return this.mul(c, scalar)};

  return forEachMatrixElement(matrix, fn);
}
```

Comment: So something like `const fn = (c: Complex) => c.mul(scalar);` for the function then?

Comment: Or I guess it would be `const fn = function(this: Complex) { this.mul(scalar); }` if you're using `.call`

Comment: Return is missing. But the answer is correct. Thank you. Would you like to complete it?:
 const fn = function(this: Complex) { return this.mul(scalar); }

Comment: Right you are, thank you. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) `Function.call()` can take additional parameters as arguments. So the first parameter will always be the `this` bind, the second and onwards are arguments.

Wonder if this is what will solve your issue? So your code will look like

```
function forEachMatrixElement(matrix: Complex[][], func: Function, scalar?: Complex)
```

and

```
func.call(matrix[row][col], scalar)
```

Comment: I don't want to add additional arguments to forEachMatrixElement. The provided function func has to be complete